# Change owl-carousel wrapper class?

Tags: javascript, html, owl-carousel

I'm using `owl-carousel` and I'm trying to replace the `owl-stage-outer` class, with `owl-wrapper-outer`
unfortunately I cannot find any options in the documentation that allow me to do this.
Here my initialization of the carousel:

```
$("#owl-featured").owlCarousel({
        nav: true,
        navText : ['<i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>','<i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>'],
        items : 3,
        itemsDesktop : [1440,3],
        itemsDesktopSmall : [1024,3],
        itemsTablet: [768,2],
        itemsTabletSmall: [719,1],
        itemsMobile : [479,1],
    });
```

so essentially the structure instead of this:

```
<div id="owl-featured" class="owl-carousel owl-theme owl-loaded owl-drag">
    <div class="owl-stage-outer">
```

should be like this:

```
<div id="owl-featured" class="owl-carousel owl-theme owl-loaded owl-drag">
    <div class="owl-wrapper-outer">
```

how can I do that? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of this option given in the docs `stageOuterClass:'your class here'`

JS

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
        stageOuterClass:'owl-wrapper-outer',
    margin:10,
    nav:true,
});
```

[link for reference](https://jsfiddle.net/DChandraShekhar/px679m03/2/)